# iOS Passbook equivalent for Android

Tags: nexus-6p

When I would board planes on airlines like Delta and United during my time with an iPhone, I would load the boarding pass into the Passbook app (which became the Wallet app with iOS 9) and would not have to print out my boarding pass. Now I have an Android phone and a United flight tomorrow. How can I use a United boarding pass digitally on my Nexus 6P? Is there a Passbook-like app for Android or do most airlines support in-app digital boarding passes, so I can board the flight with just the United app and no printed pass maybe?

US domestic flight, if that matters. Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Yesterday I searched for "wallet" in Play Store and there were apps that seemed like to work like Wallet on iOS. I'm not sure though, because that wasn't what I looked for. Maybe that's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was not necessary to use any other app; the United app itself allowed me to store the boarding pass digitally. And I assume it's the same for other airlines' Android apps (you just need to download them). Easy enough.